# how to put items of different sized lists as class parameters?

Tags: android, list, class, kotlin, android-room

I have to use a class as android room entity. I want to instantiate every object putting every list item as parameter.  There is a list with different size for each object.

```
@Entity
data class Riga(
    @PrimaryKey var dataengNuova: String?=null,
    var dataengVecchia: Long?=null,
    var numggeng: Long?=null,
    var dataitaVecchia: Long?=null,
    var dataitaNuova: Long?=null,
    var numggita: Long?=null,
    var dataudioNuova: Long?=null,
    var dataudioVecchia: Long?=null,
    var numggaudio: Long?=null
    var datangVecchia: Long?=null,
    var numggng: Long?=null,
    var dataitaecchia: Long?=null,
    var dataitauova: Long?=null,
    var numggia: Long?=null,
    var dataudoNuova: Long?=null,
    var datauoVecchia: Long?=null,
    var numggadio: Long?=null
    var numgia: Long?=null,
    var dataudNuova: Long?=null,
    var datauoecchia: Long?=null,
    var numggdio: Long?=null)
```

How can I do it whereas the list for every object has different size?

i want from something  like this:

```
var firstObjectParams= listOf(1,2,4,6)
var secondObjectParams= listOf(6,79,4657,7885,56777,5657,5677,6776)
```

something like this:

```
obj1=Riga('hg',1,2,4,6)
obj2=Riga('hk',6,79,4657,7885,56777,5657,5677,6776)
```

but i have hundreds of lists that have from 1to20items.

I know i can write twenty `if (list.size==number)` statements. i was wondering about an easier way.

Comment: Could you please add an example how you would imagine it to look like?

Comment: Do you want to add the list as a parameter or do you want to add the items in the list as a parameter? In the 2nd scenario, how are the list items related to the fields in your class?

Comment: @Neo sorry, edited

Comment: @Froyo sorry edited

Comment: Follow up question : Are these fields also written or read from the database?

Comment: @Froyo Nope, they are generated from html parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is just another constructor:

```
@Entity
data class Riga(
    @PrimaryKey var dataengNuova: String?=null,
    var dataengVecchia: Long?=null,
    var numggeng: Long?=null,
    ...
) {

  constructor(values: List<Int>) : this(
     values.getOrNull(0),
     values.getOrNull(1),
     values.getOrNull(2),
     ...
  )
}
```

So passing a list would initalise the Class. If editing the Entity is not possible, create a builder / factory with the same approach.

Comment: very good! this is a very interesting solution! maybe this is cleaner       ` var obj=Riga(list.getOrNull(0),list.getOrNull(1)...list.getOrNull(20)) `                       No need to modify list or class! Perfect! thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was easy. i have preprocessed lists to be of twenty items. Better solutions are welcome.

```
var list=mutableListOf<Int?>(2,4,5)
repeat(20 - list.size){ list.add(null) }
```

Comment: How do you instantiate a `Riga` with this list? Your code could be a bit more concise replacing the last four lines with `repeat(20 - list.size){ list.add(null) }`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `var obj=Riga(list[0],list[1]...list[20])` thank you! that repeat fun is the icing on the cake. Editing the answer with your suggestion